# What Fold should I use in VIM?

Tags: text-editor, vim

I usually edit RUBY files in VIM. I want the methods(def...end) to fold. Could you please help me define the fold syntax?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

I don't see the connection between the shiftwidth, ruby, and the fold syntax?  They seem like three unrelated items to me.

Comment: Yes I can't see it too, please clarify ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you've already got Ruby syntax highlighting setup and working, use the `syntax` mode for folding:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

This will give you folds on `class` .. `end` and `def` .. `end`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I like to have everything fold by default, and this here will let you tweak a whole bunch of things related to folding. I do mostly Perl and C++ coding and I find it works well with that. Folding and unfolding is mapped to space key.

Here's what I have going in my vimrc:

```
  " Folding stuff
  hi Folded guibg=red guifg=Red cterm=bold ctermbg=DarkGrey ctermfg=lightblue
  hi FoldColumn guibg=grey78 gui=Bold guifg=DarkBlue
  set foldcolumn=2
  set foldclose=
  set foldmethod=indent
  set foldnestmax=10
  set foldlevel=0
  set fillchars=vert:\|,fold:\
  set foldminlines=1
 " Toggle fold state between closed and opened.
  "
  " If there is no fold at current line, just moves forward.
  " If it is present, reverse it's state.
  fu! ToggleFold()
     if foldlevel('.') == 0
         normal! l
     else
         if foldclosed('.') < 0
             . foldclose
         else
             . foldopen
         endif
     endif
     echo
  endf

" Map this function to Space key.
  noremap <space> :call ToggleFold()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you put the cursor on the first line then zfnj where n is the number of lines to fold (so to fold 10 lines you woudl zf10j).  I think it will also recognize syntax so like in PHP I do zf} to fold to the closing bracket.  I don't code in Ruby, so I don't know if this works in Ruby.

From then on, to toggle, zo will open and zc will close.